# can't run a program that uses sfml in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sfml

I am running Linux Mint. The version information is as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lisa
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 12 Lisa"
```

I installed sfml by downloading the tar file, going into the sfml folder, and running `sudo make install`. It does not give me any error messages so it seems safe to assume that it installed successfully.

I wrote the clock.cpp program given in [this tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-linux.php). I compile it using the following commands:

```
$ g++ -c clock.cpp
$ g++ -o clock clock.o -lsfml-system
```

It gives me no output, so I assume that the compilation went just fine. But the problem starts when I try to run it. This is the result of me trying to run the clock executable:

```
$ ./clock
./clock: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-system.so.1.6: 
         cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I try the second compilation option that the tutorial gives, and the same thing happens:

```
$ g++ -c clock.cpp
$ g++ -o clock clock.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
./clock: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-system.so.1.6: 
         cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why can't I run the program?

Comment: distribution of linux?

Comment: Linux Mint. I edited to add version info just now.

Comment: "I installed sfml by downloading the tar file, going into the sfml folder, and running sudo make install." Are you shortening it for the sake of asking the question? I figure you have to go through the traditional steps: `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`. I recommend you install them using your system's package manager though, if the version is correct.

Comment: all *-dev libraries are installed correctly? `apt-get build-dep libsfml` maked?

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña there's no configure file in the folder. The tutorial only said to use `sudo make install`.

Comment: @mkjasinski when I try that, it says `E: Unable to find a source package for libsfml`.

Comment: @ZettaSuro run after that: `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install development library for libsfml:

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

next step:

```
apt-get build-dep libsfml
```

dev version of package is required because header files are necessary

such special libraries are usually installed with apt

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but you must run it as superuser.

```
sudo ./a.out
```