# sfml compile error: NULL was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, sfml

I am running Linux Mint. The version information is as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lisa
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 12 Lisa"
```

I am attempting to compile and link files for a C++ program that uses sfml. When attempting to compile the files, I get the following error:

```
$g++ -c lineTest.cpp Rasterizer.cpp simpleCanvas.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/include/SFML/System/Resource.hpp:211:0,
             from /usr/local/include/SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp:31,
             from simpleCanvas.h:13,
             from simpleCanvas.cpp:9:
/usr/local/include/SFML/System/ResourcePtr.inl: 
In constructor ‘sf::ResourcePtr< <template-parameter-1-1> >::ResourcePtr()’:
/usr/local/include/SFML/System/ResourcePtr.inl:31:12: 
error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/SFML/System/ResourcePtr.inl: In member function ‘void sf::ResourcePtr< <template-parameter-1-1> >::OnResourceDestroyed()’:
/usr/local/include/SFML/System/ResourcePtr.inl:148:18: error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope
```

It seems to have a problem with the use of "NULL" in the file ResourcePtr.inl. Personally, I would normally refrain from using this keyword and instead use 0, but what can I do when it's used in a package file that I myself didn't even write? Moreover, without my administrator privileges, I would not be able to edit the file to correct it, but I used sudo to edit it and added `#include <cstddef>`. This opened the floodgates to a cavalcade of similar problems where something "wasn't defined" or a keyword or type was unrecognized (the list is far too long for me to post here). This seems to indicate that something is missing from the library. I had quite a bit of trouble setting up the library initially, so I realize I may not have done it correctly. You can see it in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455914/cant-run-a-program-that-uses-sfml-in-linux). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and/or what I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does not compile and shows the errors you described:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
In file included from ./include/SFML/System/Resource.hpp:211:0,
                 from ./include/SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp:31,
                 from test.cpp:1:
./include/SFML/System/ResourcePtr.inl: In constructor ‘sf::ResourcePtr< <template-parameter-1-1> >::ResourcePtr()’:
./include/SFML/System/ResourcePtr.inl:31:12: error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope
./include/SFML/System/ResourcePtr.inl: In member function ‘void sf::ResourcePtr< <template-parameter-1-1> >::OnResourceDestroyed()’:
./include/SFML/System/ResourcePtr.inl:148:18: error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope
```

Luckily the fix is easy, this works:

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

It looks like this works too:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

They forgot to include this header somewhere in their code before using `NULL`. As long as you include it before any of their headers it should work.

As you said yourself, the use of `NULL` can be a bit confusing, as it is itself a macro expanding either to `0` or `(void*)0`. The new standard takes care of that by introducing `nullptr`, which is strongly typed. Changing `NULL` for `nullptr` in lines 31 and 148 of ResourcePtr.inl is probably the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: It is worth noting that `(void*)0` is the usual definition of `NULL` in C, but it cannot be so in C++. In C++98 it must be an integral constant of value 0 such as `0` or `0L`.